# Can not install ChIPseeker or ChIPpeakAnno

Tags: r

I can not install packages named 'ChIPpeakAnno' or 'ChIPseeker' from BiocManager. It always says that a package named 'GenomeInfoDb' can't be loaded.

And when I tried to install 'GenomeInfoDb', it says:
installation of package ‘GenomeInfoDbData’ had non-zero exit status.

I've reinstalled R and R studio, and tried to run R studio as administrator, it didn't work.

```
> library(ChIPseeker)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ChIPseeker’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
  ‘GenomeInfoDbData’ という名前のパッケージはありません 
> BiocManager::install('GenomeInfoDbData')
'getOption("repos")' replaces Bioconductor standard repositories, see '?repositories' for details

replacement repositories:
    CRAN: https://cran.rstudio.com/

Bioconductor version 3.15 (BiocManager 1.30.18), R 4.2.1 (2022-06-23 ucrt)
Installing package(s) 'GenomeInfoDbData'
 ソースパッケージ ‘GenomeInfoDbData’ をインストール中です 

trying URL 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.15/data/annotation/src/contrib/GenomeInfoDbData_1.2.8.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 11512907 bytes (11.0 MB)
downloaded 11.0 MB

Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
  cannot open the connection
Calls: source -> file
In addition: Warning message:
In file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
  cannot open file 'renv/activate.R': No such file or directory
Execution halted

 ダウンロードされたパッケージは、以下にあります 
    ‘C:\Users\ilove\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpcFS51Z\downloaded_packages’ 
Old packages: 'Matrix', 'openssl'
Update all/some/none? [a/s/n]: 
a

  利用できるバイナリー版がありますがソース版は後者です:
        binary source needs_compilation
Matrix   1.5-0  1.5-1              TRUE
openssl  2.0.2  2.0.3              TRUE

  Binaries will be installed
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.2/Matrix_1.5-0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 4512813 bytes (4.3 MB)
downloaded 4.3 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.2/openssl_2.0.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 2645671 bytes (2.5 MB)
downloaded 2.5 MB

 パッケージ ‘Matrix’ は無事に展開され、MD5 サムもチェックされました 
 パッケージ ‘openssl’ は無事に展開され、MD5 サムもチェックされました 

 ダウンロードされたパッケージは、以下にあります 
    C:\Users\ilove\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpcFS51Z\downloaded_packages 
Warning message:
In install.packages(...) :
   パッケージ ‘GenomeInfoDbData’ のインストールは、ゼロでない終了値をもちました 
> BiocManager::install('GenomeInfoDbData')
'getOption("repos")' replaces Bioconductor standard repositories, see '?repositories' for details

replacement repositories:
    CRAN: https://cran.rstudio.com/

Bioconductor version 3.15 (BiocManager 1.30.18), R 4.2.1 (2022-06-23 ucrt)
Installing package(s) 'GenomeInfoDbData'
 ソースパッケージ ‘GenomeInfoDbData’ をインストール中です 

trying URL 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.15/data/annotation/src/contrib/GenomeInfoDbData_1.2.8.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 11512907 bytes (11.0 MB)
downloaded 11.0 MB

Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
  cannot open the connection
Calls: source -> file
In addition: Warning message:
In file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
  cannot open file 'renv/activate.R': No such file or directory
Execution halted

 ダウンロードされたパッケージは、以下にあります 
    ‘C:\Users\ilove\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpcFS51Z\downloaded_packages’ 
Old packages: 'Matrix', 'openssl'
Update all/some/none? [a/s/n]: 
n
Warning message:
In install.packages(...) :
   パッケージ ‘GenomeInfoDbData’ のインストールは、ゼロでない終了値をもちました 
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22000)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.932  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.932    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.932
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          LC_TIME=English_United States.932    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] IRanges_2.30.1      digest_0.6.29       bitops_1.0-7        stats4_4.2.1        evaluate_0.16       rlang_1.0.5         cli_3.4.0          
 [8] S4Vectors_0.34.0    rmarkdown_2.16      tools_4.2.1         RCurl_1.98-1.8      xfun_0.33           yaml_2.3.5          fastmap_1.1.0      
[15] compiler_4.2.1      BiocGenerics_0.42.0 BiocManager_1.30.18 htmltools_0.5.3     knitr_1.40         
>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
  cannot open the connection
Calls: source -> file
In addition: Warning message:
In file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
  cannot open file 'renv/activate.R': No such file or directory
Execution halted
```

Best guess; you have a call to `source("renv/activate.R")` within your user `.Rprofile`, or your project `.Rprofile`. If it's within your user profile, you should remove it; if it's within your project profile, you should call `renv::activate()` to ensure that `renv` is activated in that project.